# SEO Friendly URLs where the phrase used may change in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have http://www.mysite.com/I-Like-Cheeseburgers and I want that to point to Item with id 3.  Sometime later, I change the name of the item, and now its http://www.mysite.com/I-Like-Hamburgers (and perhaps many more times).  I want all these URLs to remain pointing to Item 3.   Is it efficient to simply keep a table of [strings,item_ids] and do a lookup on this?  Is there a better way?

Comment: One thing to consider here would be SEO back links. If someone links to your site at http://www.mysite.com/I-Like-Cheeseburgers and then you change it to http://www.mysite.com/I-Like-Hamburgers then the first link will likely get a 404 page and the website owner will likely remove the link. So try to pick a solution that will alow you to not lose any inbound traffic or SEO.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can do like stackoverflow.com

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887068/seo-friendly-urls-where-the-phrase-used-may-change-in-rails
```

You keep the question ID (2887068) in the link, where the text part can be changed and still will land in the same page. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887068/whatever-you-put` or `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887068/` will send you to the same page.

so for your example it would be :

```
http://www.mysite.com/items/3/I-Like-Cheeseburgers
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use plugin [friendly_id](http://github.com/norman/friendly_id).

With `:use_slug` option it maintains history of permalinks and offer solutions to redirect to current URL etc.

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_friendly_id :title, :use_slug => true
end
```

See [documentation](http://norman.github.com/friendly_id/file.Guide.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

in your model do

```
class Article < AR::Base
  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{name.parameterize}"
  end
end
```

Your links will look like: http://mysite.com/articles/3-i-like-cheeseburgers

When you try to fetch the object, doing `Article.find(params[:id])` would automagically convert the "3-i-like-cheeseburgers" into an integer and fetch the correct object. This allows the name to change, while maintaining the link to point to the same article object.